# Could not link any Google Account to Clasp CLI for App Script creation

Tags: command-line-interface, google-authentication, clasp

I want to create a new app script for Google Sheets and I do want to use the [`clasp` CLI](https://github.com/google/clasp) provided by Google.

I tried to log in using `clasp login` and `clasp login --no-localhost` and both way result in an unknown authentication error from Google after you chose your account.
Getting an unknown error after choosing the account I want to use.
I tried to clear the cache of my browser (Firefox v100), to reboot my computer to change network and to use another account.

I did activate the Google App Script in the settings for the ones who wonder.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do to fix this issue. This is really stopping me in what I need to do.

Thanks for any answers

```js
# Specifications

- Node version (`node -v`): v18.4.0
- Version (`clasp -v`): v2.4.1
- OS (Mac/Linux/Windows): Linux - PopOS (Ubuntu like) v22.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error myself, I had an extension on my browser that clears URLs and that made every Google API call to fail.

If you get a similar error, try to check your extension.